# Flutter - setState is not Updating inner Custom Stateful widget

Tags: flutter, dart, cross-platform, flutter-layout

I have created a Custom Segments widget which creates Multiple TABS according to List. I am updating `selectionsList` from `homepage.dart` but still, my segments are not updating runtime according to changed `selectionsList`

**Segments.dart** (Custom SegmentWidget which creates Cupertino tabs)

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SegmentsWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SegmentsWidgetState createState() => _SegmentsWidgetState();

  final List selectionsList;
  final ValueChanged<int> onSelectTab;
  final VoidCallback onTap;
  final int selectedValue;

  SegmentsWidget(
      {this.selectionsList, this.onSelectTab, this.onTap, this.selectedValue});
}

class _SegmentsWidgetState extends State<SegmentsWidget> {
  Map<int, Widget> tabWidget = Map<int, Widget>();
  int selectedTab = 0;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("INit State ${widget.selectionsList}");
    setState(() {
      widget.selectionsList.asMap().forEach((index, value) {
        tabWidget.addAll({
          index: Container(
              height: 40,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  widget.selectionsList[index],
                  style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Exo2', fontSize: 12.0),
                ),
              ))
        });
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(SegmentsWidget oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    print("Did update");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Container(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: SizedBox(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: CupertinoSegmentedControl<int>(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
                children: tabWidget,
                onValueChanged: (int index) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedTab = index;
                  });
                  widget.onSelectTab(index);
                },
                groupValue: widget.selectedValue ?? selectedTab,
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**HomePage.dart**

From Home Page, I am updating **selection** array but still my segments are not updating according to **selectionList**.

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  List<String> selection;
  int selectedTab = -1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    selection = ["A", "B"];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Dynamic Segments")),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[

            SegmentsWidget(
              selectionsList: selection,
              onSelectTab: (selectTab) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedTab = selectTab;
                });
              },
            ),

            RaisedButton(child: Text("AB"),onPressed: (){
              setState(() {
                selection = ["A", "B"];
              });

            }),


            RaisedButton(child: Text("ABC"),onPressed: (){
              setState(() {
                selection = ["A", "B", "C"];
              });

            }),

          RaisedButton(child: Text("ABCD"),onPressed: (){
            setState(() {
              selection = ["A", "B", "C","D"];
            });

      })
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I assume that  **initState** of Segment Widget called once only. I even tried in **didUpdateWidget** but still not getting updated tabs.

**Issue:** How to update **tabWidgets** which is mentioned in my custom widget from another stateful widget?

Comment: initState will be called only once, you need to move that logic to `Widget build(BuildContext context)`.

Comment: Even I am moving that logic to build method it gives range error. *RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..1, inclusive: 2*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I change some parts of code. 
Instead of calling your code (that need to be called again on setState) in initState() function, call your code inside the widget with your own method.

see `getTabChilds()` function below of code.

```
class _SegmentsWidgetState extends State<SegmentsWidget> {
  Map<int, Widget> tabWidget = Map<int, Widget>();
  int selectedTab = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("INit State ${widget.selectionsList}");
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(SegmentsWidget oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    print("Did update");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: SizedBox(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: CupertinoSegmentedControl<int>(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
                children: getTabChilds(),
                onValueChanged: (int index) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedTab = index;
                  });
                  widget.onSelectTab(index);
                },
                groupValue: widget.selectedValue ?? selectedTab,
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Map<int, Widget> getTabChilds() {
    tabWidget = Map<int, Widget>();
    widget.selectionsList.asMap().forEach((index, value) {
      tabWidget.addAll({
        index: Container(
            height: 40,
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                widget.selectionsList[index],
                style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Exo2', fontSize: 12.0),
              ),
            ))
      });
    });
    return tabWidget;
  }
}
```

It's tested and works fine.